# What is a good Silverlight resource for finding out what controls are available and what they're for?

Tags: xaml, user-controls, silverlight-4.0

I'm used to winforms development, haven't done any WPF and I'm starting a Silverlight project. I understand xaml and all (and I've got some resources for learning it) but I'm wondering if there's any resources available that shows what controls are used in what kinds of situations.

For instance, if you look at the BusinessApplication template in vs2010, they use a border or a grid in cases where I would think of a panel. Things like that.

I'm looking for more of a 'tips' kind of thing than a tutorial or reference. References normally just say what a control is; not when, where or why you would use a particular control.

Answer (score 1):

These two should help you out...

http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/Silverlight/SampleBrowser/#/?sref=HomePage

http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html